# Create function area_triangle_rectangle that takes the base, height, and the kind of shape and calculates its area

Tags: python

Can someone correct/clean this for me?
Doesn't seem to work

```
def area_triangle_rectangle(base,height,shape):
    if  input(shape == "triangle"): 
        area = 0.5*base*height 
    else:
        area = base*height
    return area
    
shape = input('enter shape (rectangle or triangle)')
base = int(input('enter shape base length'))
height = int(input('enter shape base height'))


print('Area of the shape is', area_triangle_rectangle(base,height,shape))
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `input` asks the user for a value, you may not call it into your if, you already have your shape variable

```
def area_triangle_rectangle(base,height,shape):
    if shape == "triangle": 
        area = 0.5*base*height 
    else:
        area = base*height
    return area
```

You can inline in

```
def area_triangle_rectangle(base, height, shape):
    return (0.5 if shape == "triangle" else 1) * base * height
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening when you do:

```
input(shape == "triangle")
```

is that it is computing the value of `shape == "triangle"`, which is a boolean `True` or `False`, and using it as the argument to the `input` function, which then gets used as the text of the prompt when asking for input.  This argument would normally be a string, but it will accept other data types and convert them into a string to use as the prompt.

In this case, you simply want the boolean value itself: `shape == "triangle"`.